# Azure web hook error: The 'code' query parameter provided in the HTTP request did not match the expected value

Tags: azure, mobile

I have created a c# based web hook in an azure function app, based on Adrian Halls excellent book on github.io

The web hook and app is running successfully when tested in portal.
When i call the webhook from my controller i can see i have the correct parameters and uri. But for some reason my function app never enters my method and give me an error saying:

```
  The 'code' query parameter provided in the HTTP request did not match the expected value
```

My problem is that i do have my code query parameter in the request.
Basically i just want to trigger the webhook when a new todoitem is inserted in my database.

Anybody know what could be the problem?

Code:
Call from api controller to webhook method in backend

```
    // POST tables/TodoItem
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostTodoItem(TodoItem item)
{
    TodoItem current = await InsertAsync(item);
    Webhook.SendAsync<TodoItem>(new Uri(WebhookUri), current);
    return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
}
```

Webhook method in backend

```
    public static async Task<HttpStatusCode> SendAsync<T>(Uri uri, T data)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.BaseAddress = uri;

    var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<T>("",data);
    return response.StatusCode;
}
```

Function in azure

```
    #r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static async Task<object> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("Webhook triggered");
    string jsonContent = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonContent);

    log.Info($"Created New Todo ({data.Text}, {data.Complete})");

    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same issue today. Go to the Manage panel of your Azure Function. There you can copy the "default" key which works

Answer (score 2):

Anders,

There are indeed some issues with the key management UI on the portal and those are being addressed (you can track one that was likely impacting you [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/AzureFunctionsPortal/issues/828)

A workaround, at the moment, is to make sure you're using the appropriate key by opening the "keys" panel for the function and selecting the "default" function key, using that as the code.

There is also an API you can use to request the keys directly from the runtime, here's an example of invoking that API to retrieve the keys for a given function:
https://<functionappname>.azurewebsites.net/admin/functions/<functionname>/keys?code=<your admin key>

Comment: admin or function key? the default url uses function key

Comment: To consume the API? The admin key is required.

Comment: I believe in you but if you compare the keys with the default function url you will notice that the query string is ?code=defaultFunctionKey.At least in my case. Anyway in my logic app I substituted the azure function activity with the http using the function url and it works. It has to be something between Logic app and Azure functions

Comment: The instruction above was addressing an issue that no longer exists in the current portal. The admin API (which is what I was referring to) does require the admin key.

Answer (score 1):

This must be a bug in azure functions app.
I created a couple of web hook functions more to see if i could hit one of those.
No success same error as before.
But then i went back to my old function and suddenly it worked. I don't know why one of my new web hooks i tested on is a copy of the old one and it is still not working. Maybe an azure functions expert know more about this.

Comment: Same here today